# Varaha avatar is confusing!

Tags: vishnu, puranas, varaha, bhumi

So the common perception is that Narakasura was born of Bhu Devi and Varaha but it doesn’t say that in Vishnu Puran or in Bhagawat Puran.

Actually it does not even say that Varaha and Bhu Devi married! Which purana has that story?

Was Narakasur only the earths son? And if so if Varaha and the earth did not get married, then how does the Satyabhama tale fit in? Is Bhu Devi married to Vishnu or only Varaha? Considering that it was Krishna who killed Narakasura, ultimately, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Brahma Purana says that Naraka was the son of Varaha -

> "*O lord, **when I was lifted up by you in the form of **a Boar**, this son had been born of me as a result of my contact with you.** He had
> been given to me by you and now has been struck down by you.*"

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216250.html

Answer (score 0):

[The Bhagawata Purana 10.59](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128933.html).:

> 30(A). When I was lifted by you, O Lord, in your boar incarnation, this son (Naraka) was born of me in consequence of your contact. So you gave that son to me and now he has been struck down by you.

[Present in Yande’s Bombay edition in the footnote (P. 857).]

I hope this helps. Prd..